# Can I get the likes that I gave to my friend's posts from the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

Throug the Facebook Graph API explorer, I can get my likes on third pages through:

```
GET /v2.6/me/likes HTTP/1.1 Host: graph.facebook.com
```

But, what if I want to get my likes on my friend's posts, considering that are my likes I think I should be able to access to them without any permission of my friends, is it ok? How can I access to my likes?

Answer (score 0):

There is only the list of Page likes (`/me/likes`), it is not possible to get a list of all your likes on posts of friends. Also, accessing posts of friends would not be possible without them approving your App too - except for posts on your own wall.